# Uniq index but allows to have multiple records per user environments

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have 3 tables:

Users, with columns:

- id

Websites, with columns:

- id
- url
- user_id
- environment_id

Environments:

- id
- user_id

User can have many environments, environment belongs to one user only.

Website url must be uniq per environment_id.

Website url must be uniq in a way that only one user can have it.

Environments are owned by users, each user has its own set of environments, environments are not shared between users.

I expect to be able to make database level validation to prevent other users from creating websites with an url that us used by other users.

Comment: You can't do this with built-in constraints. You can use a trigger to check it whenever the tables are updated.

Comment: You can do "Website url must be uniq per environment" with a unique multi-column index: `UNIQUE INDEX (user_id, environment_id)`

Comment: @Barmar's comment here is correct, assuming that two different users could possibly use the same environment_id. If users don't share environment_id values, then simply `UNIQUE INDEX (environment_id)` ensures that there's at most one row with any `environment_id` value and so there can't be more than one `url` value in that one row.

Comment: @karmakaze two different users can't use same environment. environment belongs to user

Answer (score 0):

To make this enforced by the database, you need three tables:

Users:

- id

Urls:

- id
- url (with a UNIQUE constraint)
- user_id (reference to `Users`)

Websites:

- id
- url_id (reference to `Urls`)
- environment_id

This way each URL references exactly one user. But the `Websites` table allows each url to have multiple environments.

Comment: what would you recommend if url is too long to index?

Comment: [URL max length should be 2083 characters](https://www.sistrix.com/ask-sistrix/technical-seo/site-structure/url-length-how-long-can-a-url-be), which can be indexed in the current version of InnoDB if the column uses a single-byte character set.

Comment: If the app needs a longer URL, or needs UTF8 URLs, then use a functional index: `UNIQUE KEY (((UNHEX(MD5(url))))`.

Comment: its a solution, but I wanted to check if there might be special index for this case.